# How to create a report table about machine learning models?

Tags: r

I have applied random Forest in the models seen below and i want to create a report table with the Classification Rates, stratified by PERCENTAGE and DIETS.

I have tried the table1 function from the package table1, which gives me the form i want, but the data inside is plain descriptive data.

```
df <- data.frame(model = c("R ~ I + A + S", 
                          "R ~ log(I) + A + S", 
                          "R ~ exp(I) + A + S" ), 
                 PERCENTAGE = factor(rep(c(0, 1), each = 6)), 
                 DIETS = factor(rep(c("High Protein", "Low Protein"), each = 
                                      3)),
                 CR = runif(12), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

table1::table1(~model|DIETS * PERCENTAGE, data = df) #correct format, but incorrect data :(
```

Is there a way to get the same format as the table1 function, but with the CR(classification rate) data in it?

Answer (score 0):

An approximate solution could be the library `kableExtra`, see the section **Grouped Columns / Rows** in:

http://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_html.html#grouped_columns__rows

View the output using the *Viewer tab* in RStudio.